# How can I move/redirect single blog posts from one blog to another?

Tags: redirect, seo, migration

I see lots of answers about moving entire blogs, but here's my scenario:

I have a few blogs with a lot of content.  I'm no longer publishing new content on these sites.  I'm now publishing on another (new) site.  I don't want to migrate all of the content from the previous sites, but I'd like to move a few "greatest hits" posts.  What's the best way to migrate a few single posts from one site to another?

I'm thinking that for SEO purposes, it would make sense to have a redirect in place so that the posts currently receiving search traffic will pass that traffic onto the new site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way of doing that is actually by just copying the post to your new blog, and on your old blog, add a rel="canonical" link to that page to your new post's URL. This will notify Google and other SE's that you want to have the other, new, page ranking, without actually having to annoy your users.

There are several plugins that can do canonical, two of them are mine, if you're not doing a lot of work on those old sites i'd recommend using [my canonical plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/canonical/).

Comment: As a bonus, Google seems to pick up rel canonical faster than redirects.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do using Tools->Export. For your greatest hit posts, create a new category and categorize the posts you wish to export. Then, go to Tools->Export and click the posts radio button. You will see a drop down of criteria for the export. Select your category from the list, save the wxr file, and import it into your new site.

There are several ways to go about redirects, you can add code to your htaccess file or hook into an early action to check a post for the category you created, then set headers and redirect from there.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many individual posts you want to redirect, you could put together an .htaccess file to 301 redirect the "greatest hits" specifically, then send everything else to your new domain root.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirect specific posts
RewriteRule ^old/post/$ http://www.newdomain.com/new/post/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^some/other/post/$ http://www.newdomain.com/another/new/post/ [R=301,L]
# etc..

# redirect everything else that didn't match above
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```